# detect any pattern from a character vector within another character vector in R

Tags: r, string, stringr

I would like to return a logical vector with TRUE values for all elements in which any element from another character vector is detected.

Example data:

```
lorem <- c("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
            "Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.",
            "Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
```

As an example, I would like to search the elements 'sit' and 'non'.

I tried

```
str_detect(lorem, c('sit', 'non'))
```

and

```
str_detect(lorem, c('non', 'sit'))
```

which showed me that the second argument is probably being recycled, so the call str_detect(lorem, c('sit', 'non')) actually occurs as follows:

```
c(str_detect(lorem[1], 'sit'), str_detect(lorem[2], 'non'), str_detect(lorem[3], 'sit'), str_detect(lorem[4], 'non'))
```

I eventually came up with the following solution:

```
multi_string_detect<-function(x,y){
        temp<-sapply(y, function(z){str_detect(x, z)})
        apply(temp, 1, any)
}

multi_string_detect(lorem, c('sit', 'non')
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Is there a clean/simpler alternative to my multi_string_detect function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to collapse the `pattern` into a single string with `|`

```
library(stringr)
str_detect(lorem, str_c(c('non', 'sit'), collapse = "|"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Comment: Hi, @akrun, thanks. I am confused with the use of the 'non|sit' string though. Not so sure how to use the | operator within a string (as in 'chacter|character'), looks weird to me.

Comment: @GuedesBF We are `paste`ing the vector elements with `str_c` into a single string

Comment: Yes I got that, I just dont understand how the operator | works when inserted into a single string, may be straightforward, but I got confused

Comment: @GuedesBF it is a regex `|` (OR) to check for either one of the words to match.  To make it more robust, you can have a word boundary as well `str_c("\\b(", str_c(c('non', 'sit'), collapse = "|"), ")\\b")`

Comment: yes but i expected a 'non'|'sit' rather than the 'non|sit' you showed. I may have to study some more, thanks again

Comment: @GuedesBF If you add the `'` inside, the regex checks for that `'` to match